# How to prevent SQL rounding decimal(18,4) output in c# side

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal, rounding

I make calculation in stored procedure and pass output parameter. It works fine execution on the SQL side.

But C# retrieves output value of type `decimal(18,4)` by automatically rounding if it is lower than 0,5 to 0, if higher than 0.5 to 1.

I need `decimal(18,4)` output precisely.

How can I prevent `decimal(18,4)` output value from being rounded?

C#

```
double sonuc=0;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("findHBK", Connection.Con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yaFark", yaFark);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yaTaban", yaTaban);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@sonuc", SqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;               

if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

sonuc = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Value);
```

SQL (part of a stored procedure)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[findHBK]
    (@yaTaban DECIMAL(18, 2),
     @yaFark DECIMAL(18, 2),
     @sonuc DECIMAL(18, 4) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @minhbk DECIMAL(18, 4), 
            @maxhbk DECIMAL(18, 4), 
            @hbkFark DECIMAL(18, 4)

    IF (@yaTaban BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000)
    BEGIN
        SET @maxhbk = (SELECT MAX(HBK) FROM TBL_MDHB 
                       WHERE YapiAlani BETWEEN @yaTaban AND @yaTaban + 200)
        SET @minhbk = (SELECT MIN(HBK) FROM TBL_MDHB
                       WHERE YapiAlani BETWEEN @yaTaban AND @yaTaban + 200)
        -- SET @sonuc = @maxhbk - (((@maxhbk - @minhbk) * @yaFark) / 200);
        SET @sonuc = 0.3292

        SELECT @sonuc
    END 
    SELECT @sonuc OUT
END
```

Comment: where is this variable declared `sonuc` and why don't you declare it as a double vs using the `Convert.ToDouble` function

Comment: What is the value of `cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Value` before casting to double? Could you set a break-point and see?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is the value of @sonuc correct when you execute the stored procedure?

Comment: @Win was asking you: What happens when you put a breakpoint in your C# code for this line `sonuc = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Value)`. Inspect the parameter value of `@sonuc` - is the result actually "0.3292"?

Comment: In sql it is correct. I put value "0.3292" just to see if calculation was the problem, but calculation is also ok. In c# side when breakpoint sonuc is 0.0 . (for the value "0.3232"), for the value "0,6999"  sonuc is 1. @MetroSmurf

Comment: Could you change `sonuc`  to `decimal`, and use `Convert.ToDecimal` to see any different? I would like to know right before conversion what is the value of `cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Value` *(hover the mouse on **Value** while debugging)*.

Comment: Value is 0 @Win

Comment: Add value : cmd.Parameters.Add("@sonuc", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 123.5;

Comment: I need output value from db @jdweng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer below code .

Please set Precision and Scale property of SqlParameter which you need to return .
Its will be working perfectly .

```
        cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Precision = 18;
        cmd.Parameters["@sonuc"].Scale = 4;
```

Set this property after you add parameter in SqlCommand.

It will be helpful for you .

Thanks .

Comment: I don't want to round output to 0 or 1. I need to Prevent rounding and get the actual decimal value in 4 digits after zero. (like this: 0.4567)